# Pytorch_forecasting Temporal Fusion Transformer returns NAN in prediction and best_model_path from trainer object is null

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series, pytorch-lightning

I am using Pytorch_forecasting library with NBeats and ThmporalFusionTransformer(tft) methods for univariate and multivariate forecasting in the same pipeline respectively. Univariate forecasting is working with NBeats but getting **NAN in prediction for tft**. **It's not able to return best_model_path** due to which predictions tensors are NAN. It's working fine on Jupyter notebook, but above error in pipeline.

```
best_model_path = trainer.checkpoint_callback.best_model_path
print('best_model_path', best_model_path)
best_tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.load_from_checkpoint(best_model_path)
```

best_model_path comes out empty.

**This may be because the same lightning_log folder is being used for both univariate and multivariate model. How to initialize a new lightning_log folder for new model via pytorch_lightning ?**
Below is code structure i have used.

```
def prepare_data_multivariate(train_data, test_data, selected_features, target, market, prediction_length = 6):
    if test_data is not None:
        data = pd.concat([train_data, test_data])
    else:
        data = train_data
    data = add_time_index(data, market)
    max_encoder_length = prediction_length * 4
    max_prediction_length = prediction_length

    training_cutoff = data["time_idx"].max() - max_prediction_length
    training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
        data[lambda x: x.time_idx <= training_cutoff],
        time_idx="time_idx",
        target=target,
        group_ids=['market'],
        min_encoder_length=max_encoder_length // 2,  # keep encoder length long (as it is in the validation set)
        max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length,
        min_prediction_length=1,
        max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length,
        static_categoricals=['market'],
        static_reals=[],
        time_varying_known_categoricals=[],
        variable_groups={},  # group of categorical variables can be treated as one variable
        # time_varying_known_reals=["time_idx"],
        time_varying_unknown_categoricals=[],
        time_varying_unknown_reals=selected_features,
        add_relative_time_idx=True,
        add_target_scales=True,
        add_encoder_length=True,
    )

    validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, data, predict=True, stop_randomization=True)

    batch_size = 32  
    train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
    val_dataloader = validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size * 10, num_workers=0)
    return training, train_dataloader, val_dataloader

def train_model_multivariate(training, train_dataloader, val_dataloader):
    early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=1e-4, patience=10, verbose=False, mode="min")
    lr_logger = LearningRateMonitor()  # log the learning rate
    # logger = TensorBoardLogger("lightning_logs")  # logging results to a tensorboard
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        max_epochs=30,
        gpus=0,
        weights_summary="top",
        gradient_clip_val=0.1,
        limit_train_batches=30,  # coment in for training, running valiation every 30 batches
        fast_dev_run=True,  # comment in to check that networkor dataset has no serious bugs
        callbacks=[lr_logger, early_stop_callback]
    )

    tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
        training,
        learning_rate=0.1,
        hidden_size=16,
        attention_head_size=1,
        dropout=0.1,
        hidden_continuous_size=8,
        output_size=7,  
        loss=QuantileLoss(),
        log_interval=10,  
        reduce_on_plateau_patience=4,
    )

    tf.io.gfile = tb.compat.tensorflow_stub.io.gfile

    # fit network
    trainer.fit(
        tft,
        train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
        val_dataloaders=val_dataloader,
    )
    best_model_path = trainer.checkpoint_callback.best_model_path
    best_tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.load_from_checkpoint(best_model_path)
    return best_tft
```